# Can you make an image a Hyperlink in iWork Pages '09?

Tags: macos, hyperlink, iwork-pages

I know how to make text a hyperlink in Pages '09 but when I want to link an image to a webpage, it's not giving me that option.

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there a way to make an image in a document a link to a webpage?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible in Pages. You can only hyperlink text, nothing else. 
The only workaround I can imagine goes as follows:

- Embed the image as usual.

  [image]
- Create a text box and set it to "float" with no wrapping. Then, enable the text in it as a hyperlink (replace the dummy text when you do so).

  [image]

  [image]
- Move the text box over the image, so it overlaps, then set its opacity to 0%.

  [image]

This is obviously a bit confusing, but the only way I can think of.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and suggestion. I'll test that out.

Comment: A pretty good workaround (though not very easy to maintain). Thanks for this suggestion !